# nginx proxy_set_header isn't working

Tags: python, nginx, flask

### Background

A `docker` container running a `supervisord` process with 2 processes started - `nginx` and `uwsgi` (yes I understand this may be doing docker 'wrong'. That's not the question)

The `uwsgi` hits a `python` `flask` app. This has a logger connected, and prints the headers dictionary to the info log.

I have a `postman` request that tests from my local box, hits the docker container, routes via nginx and hits the python app, with the info log appended.

Custom headers sent by postman are being logged (thanks to `ignore_invalid_headers off`;)

## The Problem

I'd like to use `nginx` to decorate incoming requests with some further headers. No matter what I try I can't get it to work. None of the headers I add in the `nginx` conf seems to make it through to the `flask` app.

I've tried proxy_set_header or uwgi_param. No variant seems to work.
Please note - I want a *request* header. I believe add_header is for response headers.

nginx.conf:

```
user nginx; 
worker_processes auto; 
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
    }

http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;        
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        underscores_in_headers      off;
        ignore_invalid_headers      off;

        upstream myapp {
            server unix:/run/myapp.sock;
        }

        server {
            listen 80;
            location / {
                include                     uwsgi_params;

                uwsgi_pass                  myapp;

                proxy_set_header            x-proxy-set-header x-proxy-set-header-value;
                proxy_set_header            sampl-header ONE;
                uwsgi_param                 X-add-uwsgi-param x-added-uwsfi-param-value;
            }
        } 
}

daemon off;
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!!

Comment: `proxy_set_header` only works with `proxy_pass`. The only (horrible) way I can think of to achieve this is to `proxy_pass` to another `nginx` port and then `uwsgi` from there.

Comment: Thanks. I literally just got it too. Answer below may help others...

Answer (score 3):

So. Solved. As Richard Smith also found- proxy_pass doesn't work as I'm using uwsgi_pass for the custom protocol.

SO. this works:

```
location / {
            include                     uwsgi_params;

            uwsgi_pass                  myapp;
            uwsgi_pass_request_headers on;
            uwsgi_param HTTP_X_TESTING 'bar';
        }
```

And we're cooking on gas...
*Air Punch*

Comment: thanks a million! Do you know why 'HTTP' prefix is required in the header key? Otherwise, it doesn't work.

Comment: hey np, glad it helped. I'm not sure. I think it's a 'std' nginx convention.

Comment: @karakays http refers to the nginx http cpre module - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html